# Community guidelines about changing the username?

Tags: support, users

It's been observed by all of us that generally lot's of users change their username frequently. It's OK and allowed on this site and users can do that at their will.

But that sometimes create problems also in identifying the exact user or person to whom we previously  were knowing and is confusing either. In this case we might not be able to communicate with that users just as  we used to as before unless we properly identify him.

So my question is are there any Stack Exchange guidelines regarding to changing of the username. For example informing the community about the change in notice for short period of time or Displaying all the previous usernames the user were having to Hi-reputation users if not to moderators only , and they can provide the  info. regarding to this as required to the rest of the users.

And are there some other guidelines like how many times a user can change his username in specific amount of time. etc. or specific to Hinduism SE !

**Note** - The question only concerns about Display name or Username and is not related to Display picture.

Comment: Related post on MSE: [Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29966/260388)

Comment: @Pandya - Yes , exact find. .

Comment: @Pandya -  You can post the answer based on that comment. It is answering most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Paṇḍyā](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/community-guidelines-about-changing-the-username#comment7713_1688) pointed out in above comments:

> [Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29966/260388)

This should answer the question.

Comment: The answer linked doesn't give any guidelines about profile name. It just gives information about limits.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the requested features are already present.

There are no hard rules in changing our user name. We can name our user profile in a funny manner also.

From [a meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/357396) about the content of user profile by Jaydles.

[image: image contains Pencil sketch of three men labelled Professional, Casual and Zandoz for Posts, User name and User profile respectively. The image is about describing profile description.]

#### A few guidelines about user name

- We should take care that both the profile name and profile picture are identical with another user. This could create a lot of confusion to readers, voters and sometimes to moderators also.
- Please avoid unicode characters in user names since they are not supported in some devices. If correct user name is not typed, you may miss notifications from chat and comments.
- Though being funny is allowed, Code of Conduct also applies to user names. If the user name is offensive, ♦️ moderators have the privilege to change it removing profanity.

There are many users who have changed their user names once or twice and a few regularly. To avoid confusion, we should remember the unique ID we are given. (For your unique ID, click on [your profile page](/users/current). It is displayed on search bar.)

If we are regular visitors of the site, we can remember some of the posts written by a specific user though their name is changed.

- Users can change their user names once in 30 days. This limit is not applied to new users and ♦️ moderators. There is a 15 minute grace period after change of user name. For more limits, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/357396)

  It is not mandatory to change once in a month or to keep the user name constant. It is our will whether or not to change the name. So, there are no strict guidelines on changing user name like the guidelines for updating our questions and answers.
- Recent names of a user within a period of time are visible to moderators.